# How to return different tokens during tokenization?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a compiler in Rust and, given a string, part of the logic is to find out of which "kind" the characters are.

I want to return the "value" of each character. For an input of `1 + 2` each character has a "token" and should return something like:

- `NumberToken`, `1`
- `WhiteSpaceToken`, `' '`
- `PlusToken`, `'+'`
- `WhiteSpaceToken`, `' '`
- `NumberToken`, `1`

My function should return something like

```rust
enum SyntaxKind {
    NumberToken,
    WhiteSpaceToken,
    PlusToken
}

struct SyntaxToken {
   kind: SyntaxKind,
   value: // Some general type
}
    
fn next_token(line: String) -> SyntaxToken  {
   // Logic goes here
}
```

How would I implement such logic?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are you asking for the code to write for `// logic goes here`?

Comment: I was trying to find some like the type "Object" that has in other languages like Java.

Sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're writing out a *tokenizer* and you wonder what such logic *might* look like, you can couple these values in the same `enum`, e.g:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Token {
    Add,
    Sub,
    Whitespace,
    Number(f64),
}
```

For more, see [The Rust Programming Language, "Defining an Enum"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html) on adding data to variants.

… and then you can use a `match` inside of an iterator to handle it accordingly:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Token {
    Add,
    Sub,
    Whitespace,
    Number(f64),
}

use std::str::Chars;
use std::iter::Peekable;

struct Tokens<'a> {
    source: Peekable<Chars<'a>>,
}

pub type TokenIterator<'a> = Peekable<Tokens<'a>>;

impl<'a> Tokens<'a> {
    pub fn new(s: &'a str) -> TokenIterator {
        Self {
            source: s.chars().peekable(),
        }
        .peekable()
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Tokens<'a> {
    type Item = Token;
    
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        match self.source.next() {
            Some(' ') => Some(Token::Whitespace),
            Some('+') => Some(Token::Add),
            Some('-') => Some(Token::Sub),
            n @ Some('0'..='9') => {
                let mut number = String::from(n.unwrap());
                
                while let Some(n) = self.source.next_if(char::is_ascii_digit) {
                    number.push(n);
                }
                
                Some(Token::Number(number.parse::<f64>().unwrap()))
            }
            Some(_) => unimplemented!(),
            None => None,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let tokens = Tokens::new("1 + 2");
    
    for token in tokens {
        println!("{:?}", token);
    }
}
```

This should then give you:

```
Number(1.0)
Whitespace
Add
Whitespace
Number(2.0)
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=73fbea744a02e1be1f53b21a2ac5ca85)

Comment: This is a good guess (and a useful contribution, I upvoted) but it is almost certainly a guess, the question isn't very clear...

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted, thank you and sorry for not being clear.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to be of some help @ianprogrammer. I've tried to clarify some parts of your post for future readers, but perhaps others can chime in as well. It was a fun question to answer on my part.